# How can I do to modify a charfiled to foreign key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I am trying using django to modify my charfield to a foreign key using :

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```

But when I do `python3 manage.py migrate` I got

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ERREUR:  the relation « myproject_django » does not exist.
```

I don't want to do `python3 manage.py --migrate` because I want to do my migrations but I don't know how to do ?

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Can you share the models.py file?

Answer (score 0):

Then simply use :-

```
   Class class_name(models.Model): 
        your_instance_name = Foreign_Key(class_name,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')
```

Remember always , you have to use migrate function in every adding or editing in Models.py :-

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```